# Pass viewbag value through input button on click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my `index` view I have a filter called `currentFilter` which I am passing to my `edit` view through the `ViewBag` like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { evpId = item.EvpId, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
```

In my edit view I have 3 submit buttons like so:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="btnSubmitSave" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save" class="btn btn-default cancel"  />
            <input id="btnSubmitResolve" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Resolve" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input id="btnSubmitUnResolvable" type="submit"name="submitButton" value="UnResolvable" class="btn btn-default cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then finally in my controller I am doing a switch which redirects to the appropriate Post action for each button.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(string submitButton, PersonViewModel modifiedPersonViewModel)
        {
         switch (submitButton)
                {
                    case "Save": return (Save(modifiedPersonViewModel));
                    case "Resolve": return (Resolve(modifiedPersonViewModel));
                    case "UnResolvable": return (UnResolvable(modifiedPersonViewModel));    
                    default: return (View());
                }
         }
```

I want to pass the `currentFilter` value through with my button click, as currently if they click save for example, when they return to the `index` view the filter is lost and they must type it in again, I just don't get how to pass this though an input tag?

Comment: I'd "stringify" the filter and save it in a hidden input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert input with type `hidden` in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="currentFilter" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
<input id="btnSubmitSave" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save" class="btn btn-default cancel"  />
<input id="btnSubmitResolve" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Resolve" class="btn btn-default" />
<input id="btnSubmitUnResolvable" type="submit"name="submitButton" value="Unresolvable" class="btn btn-default cancel"  />
```

You'll need to append `CurrentFilter` property to Edit model.
Then you can use this value in the action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string currentFilter, string submitButton, PersonViewModel modifiedPersonViewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `value="@Model.CurrentFilter"` be `value="@Request["currentFilter"]"` ?

Comment: @ekad In ASP.NET MVC direct using of form variables is a bad practice. Usually you should declare action parameters for desired form variables, and create a *model* to pass it to a view. The engine binds form variables to parameters for you.

Comment: Why ? He may be using model binding @ekad

Comment: @MarkShevchenko my Model does not contain CurrentFilter as a property, its passed through the ViewBag and is just a string from the search box

Comment: I prefer to append necessary values to model, but you can use `value="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter"` instead of `value="@Model.CurrentFilter"`.